# Story count is wrong in JBehave

Tags: java, jbehave

For some reason JBehave appears to be counting the number of stories that where executed incorrectly. In order to illustrate the behaviour I'm refering to I've set up the following minimal example - it contains a single story which runs a trivial test:

**JBehaveTest.java**

```
package test.jbehave;

import org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStory;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporterBuilder;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InjectableStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InstanceStepsFactory;

public class JBehaveTest extends JUnitStory {

  @Override
  public Configuration configuration() {
    return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
      .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass()))
      .useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder()
      .withDefaultFormats()
      .withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.TXT)); 
  }

  @Override
  public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
    return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new TestSteps());
  }
}
```

**TestSteps.java**

```
package test.jbehave;

import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class TestSteps {

  @Given("I run a test")
  public void iRunATest() {
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

**j_behave_test.story**

```
Scenario: Some random text
Given I run a test
```

Now, what I would have expected is that this runs 1 story which contains 1 scenario. But instead it actually runs 2 stories:

**Console Output**

```
Processing system properties {}
Using controls EmbedderControls[...]

(BeforeStories)

Running story test/jbehave/j_behave_test.story

(test/jbehave/j_behave_test.story)
Scenario: 
Given I run a test

(AfterStories)

Generating reports view to ...
Reports view generated with 2 stories (of which 0 pending) containing 1 scenarios (of which 0 pending)
```

I simply could not figure out why JBehave claims to have run 2 stories containing 1 scenario. I'm relatively new to JBehave so, if you do know why it counts like that, please give me hint. Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**
During the past days, I've been working with JBehave quite frequently and found that this problem comes up quite consistently in my projects. Unfortunately, I was unable to find a solution it up to this point and so the incorrect count keeps on messing with my test reports.

**UPDATE 2**
Inserted `Scenario: Some random text` into the story file.

Comment: This may be too simple (and I've not tested it) but have you tried simply adding "Scenario: " at the top of your story file?  If that doesn't change anything, I'd try it with some text follwing the colon.

Comment: @BillHileman I changed the story file to
`Scenario: Some random text
Given I run a test`
Unfortunately, I still get the same behavior i.e. 2 stories instead of one.

Comment: Have you looked at the output report?  There might actually be two stories in the report even though you only ran one.  That is by design, actually.  The stats from previously run stories (with other names) will generally remain in the reports until the data is deleted. check your target/jbehave/view/index.html file to view the html report.  If it does indeed have two stories in there, that's your problem.  The solution is to clear that folder's files as well as it's parent folder's (targe/jbehave) file and run your test again.  It should then report just the one story.

Comment: @BillHileman That's not the problem here. The HTML report shows the correct figures (i.e. 1 story and 1 step). Just to make sure I did not mess up the configuration at some point: Have you tried to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: I have not, sorry.  Is the story file located in the same folder with the test.jbehave package?  Do other story files exist?  Since you are not specifying which story/ies to run, it's likely just running every story in that folder.  I get that there's only one on the report, thanks for confirming, but perhaps another story file exists that for whatever reason is being "processed" but not reported.  I'm not familiar enough with how you would run the test with just those three files.

Comment: @BillHileman There is no other story-file in that package. Actually, the three files listed above are everything that's in there (I've created that project specifically to demonstrate the issue). In creating the project I followed the instructions on http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/getting-started.html. Is there anything in particular that you would have done differently?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in JBehave 4.x version which counts "Total" report stats when printing this information on console. However "Totals report" itself is not created. You can track this issue here https://jbehave.atlassian.net/browse/JBEHAVE-1186